# Issue upgrading from 4.34 - Fatal Error (value: is not of the type integer

Tags: upgrade

Have the following error trying to upgrade the DB, any help would be appreciated:

```
$ drush civicrm-upgrade-db
Exception: "A fatal error was triggered: One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer"
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Utils\Type.php(362): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("One of parameters
(value: ) is not of the type Integer")
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php(1247): CRM_Utils_Type::validate(NULL, "Integer")
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php(1166): CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery("UPDATE civicrm_
option_value\n        SET value = '{\"paper-size\":\"a4\",\"or...", (Array:1), TRUE)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Upgrade\Incremental\php\FourFour.php(176): CRM_Core_DAO::execut
eQuery("UPDATE civicrm_option_value\n        SET value = '{\"paper-size\":\"a4\",\"or...", (Array:1))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Upgrade\Form.php(683): CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FourFour->up
grade_4_4_1("4.4.1", "4.3.4", "4.6.5")
#5 [internal function](): CRM_Upgrade_Form::doIncrementalUpgradeStep(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), "4.4.1", "4.3.4", "4
.6.5", "C:\Users\Miles\AppData\Local\Temp\civA92E.tmp")
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Queue\Task.php(88): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:5))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Queue\Runner.php(213): CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_Tas
kContext))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Queue\Runner.php(168): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Upgrade\Headless.php(67): CRM_Queue_Runner->runAll()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\drupal\drush\civicrm.drush.inc(689): CRM_Upgrade_Headless->run()
#11 [internal function](): drush_civicrm_upgrade_db()
#12 C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc(362): call_user_func_array("drush_civicrm_upgrade_db", (Array:0))
#13 C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc(214): _drush_invoke_hooks((Array:29), (Array:0))
#14 [internal function](): drush_command()
#15 C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc(182): call_user_func_array("drush_command", (Array:0))
#16 C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php(92): drush_dispatch((Array:29))
#17 C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php(61): _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#18 C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php(16): drush_main()
#19 {main}
WD php: Exception: A fatal error was triggered: One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer in       [error]

CRM_Core_Error::fatal() (line 328 of C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Error.php).
Exception: A fatal error was triggered: One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer in CRM_Core_Error::fatal
() (line 328 of C:\xampp\htdocs\ma\html\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Error.php).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                               [error]
```

Comment: We always suggest searching.  A quick google found this. Is it of any help? https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=30158.0

Comment: Cheers Pete, yep I already saw that and 'Credit Card' is enabled

Answer (score 1):

The code that is failing is trying to update a name_badge format.  It looks like 3 new types of labels were added at some point but one of them had an issue and this code is updating that one.

It looks for the id of name_badge in the civicrm_option_group table. It uses that in this sql

```
 UPDATE civicrm_option_value
 SET value = '{$dimension}'
 WHERE option_group_id = %1 AND name = 'Fattorini Name Badge 100x65'
```

I'm guessing for some reason the array that feeds %1 is not an integer.

So what to do?  You can, as link in the comment suggest, comment out the update.  In this case in civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourFour.php around line 176 comment out this code:

```
CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery($query, array(1 => array($ogID, 'Integer')));
```

You might get the problem again with another upgrade.

You might check to see if the following sql comes back with anything

```
SELECT * FROM `civicrm_option_group` WHERE name = 'name_badge'
```

I think it will.  If so, use the id in the following query.

```
SELECT name FROM civicrm_option_value WHERE option_group_id =
```

I think you should get back four rows

```
Avery 5395
A6 Badge Portrait 150x106
Fattorini Name Badge 100x65
Hanging Badge 3-3/4" x 4-3"/4
```

If you don't get anything back from the civicrm_option_group` WHERE name = 'name_badge' query check to see if the civicrm_option_value exists

```
SELECT option_group_id, 
       name 
FROM   civicrm_option_value 
WHERE  name in ('Avery 5395',
                'A6 Badge Portrait 150x106',
                'Fattorini Name Badge 100x65',
                'Hanging Badge 3-3/4" x 4-3"/4')
```

I'm not sure how recommended this is but you can just add the missing name badge row to the civicrm_option_group table.

```
INSERT INTO `civicrm_option_group` (`name`, `title`, `is_reserved`, `is_active`, `is_locked`) 
                        VALUES ('name_badge','Name Badge Format',true, true, false)
```

Now if you got any of the four option values back you'll need to change their option_group_id to match the id of the row you added with the insert.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've had a look and there's no 'name_badge' row in that table, the closest is 'event_badge'.

Comment: I'm not sure if just editing the answer will make it pop back up for you.  I added some stuff at the end.  I will be backpacking away from electronic for the next four day so...

Comment: I ran the insert query but got an error because the is_locked column doesn't exist - worked ok without that column specified. I got an empty result set with the SELECT statement. 

Yesterday I tried running the upgrade after commenting out line 9 and that failed because my civicrm_line_item table doesn't have a contribution_id column - not sure if there is something going on with missing columns in the DB, though I found this https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/3240 which suggests that column was added after 4.34

Comment: I ran the schema changes there manually on the DB, but then got an error 'already exists' related to this https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14894 - I applied the schema update there and the upgrade completed. However, there was a WSOD after upgrade related to this https://www.drupal.org/node/2363903 - I applied the schema update and was able to load Drupal pages of the site, but there is still a WSOD with Civi, looking at the logs it's due to a missing table error (civicrm_recurring_entity).

Comment: It's as if the upgrade process isn't doing the schema updates. Could this be related to Civi being installed in a combined DB with Drupal rather than in it's own database? At the bottom of the Drupal settings.php I've spotted a bunch of lines starting like this

$databases['default']['default']['prefix']= array(
  'civicrm_acl'                              => '`dbname`.',
  'civicrm_acl_cache'                        => '`dbname`.',
  'civicrm_acl_contact_cache'                => '`dbname`.',
...